# Unable to run Java JNI code eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How do I run Java JNI code in eclipse under windows xp. I linked with the jni dll library, and I load it in java using System.loadLibrary(). However, it fails while loading the library; the program is terminated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you run Java code, C++, do you run it inside java (via a command line java invocation) ? Or in Eclipse ?

Comment: Your question contains a mess of contradictions. The question tag says "android-ndk", but an NDK libary cannot be, strictly speaking, run on Windows XP per se. You can only run it on an Android device or emulator. Also, an NDK library is never a DLL. Are you sure you're not trying to reuse a library built for desktop Java/JNI in an Android project? That'll never work.

Comment: If I follow jni instruction and build shared library, able to run it in Android. But when I build dll and going to run it in Java, I can't.

Comment: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Comment: I am able to run shared library on Android, and can access jni method from android. But when I create dll and call it from java, then I'm facing the problem. I linked with the jni dll library, and I load it in java using System.loadLibrary(). However, it fails while loading the library; the program is terminated. Please help, why System.loadLibrary() able to load shared library in android, but not load dll in java.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're linking the same architecture on the c++ and JVM side. Use 32bit JVM with 32bit c++ targets and same applies for 64 bit.